# DropDownList.DataSource NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables, nullreferenceexception

I am getting null reference in by backend CS Code. Why is the `DataTable` `null`?

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Frequency" ItemStyle-Width = "150" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Frequency"  runat="server" Text='<% # Eval("frequency") %>' ></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="frequencydropdownlist" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:DropDownList>
     </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Addfrequencydropdownlist" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class CollectionHead : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand();
        mycommand.Connection = con;
        mycommand.CommandText = "select ID,Frequency from FeesFrequency";
        mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mycommand.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = mycommand;

        sda.Fill(dtt);
        DropDownList Addfrequencydropdownlist = CollectionHead_GridView.FindControl("Addfrequencydropdownlist") as DropDownList;

        Addfrequencydropdownlist.DataSource = dtt.DefaultView;// null reference exception ????????
        Addfrequencydropdownlist.DataTextField = "Frequency";
        Addfrequencydropdownlist.DataValueField = "ID";
        Addfrequencydropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: It is `Addfrequencydropdownlist` which is `null` after your try-cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** You have to databind the grid first before you can access it's footer. Therefore i would use the `RowDataBound` event to fill the `DropDownList`:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        DropDownList Addfrequencydropdownlist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Addfrequencydropdownlist");
        // ...            
    }
}
```

---

**Old answer** (might still be useful):

It is `Addfrequencydropdownlist` which is `null` after your try-cast because the `NamingContainer` of the `DropDownList` in the footer of the grid is not the grid itself but the `FooterRow`. So this is `null` causing the  `NullReferenceException`:

```
CollectionHead_GridView.FindControl("Addfrequencydropdownlist")
```

You can use the [`FooterRow`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.footerrow(v=vs.110).aspx) of the grid to get it's reference:

```
GridViewRow footer = CollectionHead_GridView.FooterRow;
DropDownList Addfrequencydropdownlist = (DropDownList)footer.FindControl("Addfrequencydropdownlist");
```

As an aside, i would use the `as` operator only if it isn't exceptional that it is `null`. Otherwise you're replacing a menaingful `NullReferenceException` with a bug in your code(in this case a `NullReferenceException` at the wrong place).

I would also wrap it in a `if(!IsPostBack)`-check to databind it only at the initial load and not on every postback if `ViewState` is enabled(default):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
    // rest of your code in Page_Load ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help But  I am still getting the same error in your code line with the same null reference error

Comment: Thanks for your help and it has helped me as intended.